# Javascript SDK right after opening <body> tag not working

Tags: wordpress, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hello everyone this is my problem: the FB developers site states that, in order to initialize de Javascript SDK: "The best place to put this code is right after the opening `<body>` tag."

In the Header.php of my Wordpress-based blog, i have this code:

```
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true
      });
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>

<div id="pagewrap1">

        <div id="headerbg">

            <div id="header">
            <?php include (ABSPATH.'wp-content/flashfader/flashfaderhtml.txt'); ?> 

            </div>                

        </div><!-- headerbg END -->

</div><!-- ENDof #pagewrap1 -->    

<div id="pagewrap2"> 

<div id="access" role="navigation">

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

<div id="iconfacebook">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/name" title="Facebook"><img src="png"; /> </a>
</div>    
<div id="icontwt">
<a href="http://twitter.com/name" title="Sígueme"><img src="png" /></a>
</div>    
<div id="iconfeed">
<a href="feed" title="Suscribirse RSS 2.0"><img src="png" /></a>
</div>

    <div class="search-form">
            <?php $search_text = "Buscar..."; ?>
                <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/">

                <fieldset class="search">

                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $search_text; ?>" name="s" id="s" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php echo $search_text; ?>';}" onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php echo $search_text; ?>') {this.value = '';}" />

<button class="btn" title="Buscar">Search</button>    

                </fieldset>
</form>     

</div>

</div><!-- #access -->

</div><!-- ENDof #pagewrap2 -->    

<div id="pagewrap3">
```

And that's where my header.php ends.

Problem is: the registration plug in a dedicated Wordpress page doesn't work, and shows this [image](http://www.manuelmedina.com.mx/images/FB-registration-problem-1.png).

But if I place the code in a text widget on the sidebar it works, like in this other [image](http://www.manuelmedina.com.mx/images/FB-registration-problem-2.png). You can even see the sidebar margin.

What am I doing wrong with the Javascript SDK? Where should I place it? I need the registration form in a dedicated page. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Place the `<div id="fb-root" />` tag where you want Facebook content to appear.

Place the `<script>` tag at the bottom of page, immediately before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Thanks Teddy, I'll try this but, to make it clear, if I want the FB content (registration form) to appear in a dedicated page (blogURL/registry), can I place the `<div id="fb-root" />` tag right after the opening `<body>` tag in my Header.php? Or should it be in another php like the "single" or "page"? Sorry if I'm making a silly question but I'm really new at this.

Comment: It didn't work, I placed the `<script>` in footer.php as you suggested, and left the `<div id="fb-root" />` tag in the header.php (right after opening `<body>` tag, no succes. Then I tried placing the `<div id="fb-root" />` in the registry page itself nad had the same result. Can my four pagewraps be causing this? I have 4 of them (header, menubar, content and footer) and they're all between the opening and closing `<body>` tags.